# Recurrence relation has bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question regarding one-to-one mappings. I have two sets A = {1,2,3,4,5..} and B = {1,4,7,10,13,...}

I have to create a bijection between the maps. The easiest one if f(n) = 3(n)-2
However, there is a recurrence relation that can give the same output such that 
A(n+1) = A(n)+3 where A(1)=1

I wanted to know is there a way to formally do a proof to show that the recurrence relation is 1-1 and onto?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I think you would need to have some exact description of $B$ in the first place, such as the formula $3n-2$ you already know. Then one could show by induction the recurrence A gives the same sequence. But to show a recurrence does something like this one needs to know what each set "looks like" in the first place.

Comment: You can do it by showing that $A(n)=f(n)$ for all $n$.  You say you know how to do it for $f(n)$ already.  $A(n)$ is no different because it is in fact not different than $f$.